# Replacing -SNAPSHOT in pom when releasing

Tags: maven-2, continuous-integration

I am developing code actively, with my developing team. When we release to our customers, I would like to provide jars without the -SNAPSHOT so they only need to update when a new dot version is created.

This there a maven plugin that provides this functionality. I know there is because everyone else must do it some how. I doubt it is manually.

I would appreciate answers to be explicit as possible.

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some plugins can help here, as already mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660759/mvn-clean-install-vs-deploy-vs-release/3661037#3661037) and in [the comments of this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619628/deploying-maven-jar-files-and-snapshot-dependencies/3619704#3619704): the [Maven Release Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/) if you want to fully automate the release and/or the [Maven Versions Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/).

#### With the Maven Release Plugin

Releasing a project with the [Maven Release Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/) is done in two steps: [`prepare`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html) and [`perform`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/perform-release.html) and here is what the documentation writes about the [`release:prepare`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html) goal:

> Preparing a release goes through the
>   following release phases:
>
> - Check that there are no uncommitted changes in the sources
> - Check that there are no SNAPSHOT dependencies
> - **Change the version in the POMs from x-SNAPSHOT to a new version (you
>     will be prompted for the versions to
>     use)**
> - Transform the SCM information in the POM to include the final
>     destination of the tag
> - Run the project tests against the modified POMs to confirm everything is
>     in working order
> - Commit the modified POMs
> - Tag the code in the SCM with a version name (this will be prompted
>     for)
> - Bump the version in the POMs to a new value y-SNAPSHOT (these values
>     will also be prompted for)
> - Commit the modified POMs

In other words, the Maven Release Plugin is exactly doing what you're asking for.

#### With the Maven Versions Plugin

If you don't use the Maven Release Plugin, the [Maven Versions Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) can be helpful. In particular, the following goals:

> - [`versions:update-parent`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-parent-mojo.html) updates the parent section of a
>     project so that it references the
>     newest available version. For example,
>     if you use a corporate root POM, this
>     goal can be helpful if you need to
>     ensure you are using the latest
>     version of the corporate root POM.
> - [`versions:update-child-modules`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-child-modules-mojo.html)
>     **updates the parent section of the child modules of a project so the
>     version matches the version of the
>     current project.** For example, if you
>     have an aggregator pom that is also
>     the parent for the projects that it
>     aggregates and the children and parent
>     versions get out of sync, this mojo
>     can help fix the versions of the child
>     modules. (Note you may need to invoke
>     Maven with the -N option in order to
>     run this goal if your project is
>     broken so badly that it cannot build
>     because of the version mis-match).
> - [`versions:set`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html) **can be used to set the project version from the
>     command line.**
> - [`versions:commit`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/commit-mojo.html) removes the pom.xml.versionsBackup files. Forms
>     one half of the built-in "Poor Man's
>     SCM".
> - [`versions:revert`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/revert-mojo.html) restores the pom.xml files from the
>     pom.xml.versionsBackup files. Forms
>     one half of the built-in "Poor Man's
>     SCM".

I mentioned several goals but the "most" interesting is probably `versions:update-child-modules` here. It would allow to change the version in the top parent pom and then to automate the update of the child. See [Fixing a multi-module build](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/update-child-modules.html) for an example.

Can't help more, you need to experiment yourself now. Good luck!

#### References

- [The Maven Release Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/)
- [The Maven Versions Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/)